# Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code seems correct. But when I add the `Group` keyword in the query it produces a message:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'*

but when I remove the `Group` keyword the program runs successfully.

```
private void CSRMaintReviewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MaintReviewertbl.DataSource = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csrapps"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select " +
                          "EmailID_Reviewer, " +
                          "Reviewer_Name, " +
                          "Reviewer_Email, " +
                          "EmailID_TeamLead, " +
                          "TeamLead_Name, " +
                          "TeamLead_Email, " +
                          "Site, " +
                          "Business_Unit, " +
                          "Group, " +
                          "Station, " +
                          "Pkg_Department, " +
                          "Region, " +
                          "Account, " +
                          "Key_Field, " +
                          "EmailID_SiteManager, " +
                          "SiteManager_Name, " +
                          "SiteManager_Email, " +
                          "EmailID_SiteDirector, " +
                          "SiteDirector_Name, " +
                          "SiteDirector_Email, " +
                          "EmailID_President, " +
                          "President_Name, " +
                          "President_Email, " +
                          "Customer, " +
                          "Flag, " +
                          "CreatedBy, " +
                          "DateCreated, " +
                          "LastUpdatedBy, " +
                          "DateUpdated " +
                          "from dbo.tblCSRMaintReviewer ";

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MaintReviewer reviewer = new MaintReviewer();
                    reviewer.EmailIDReviewer = reader["EmailID_Reviewer"].ToString();
                    reviewer.ReviewerName = reader["Reviewer_Name"].ToString();
                    reviewer.ReviewerEmail = reader["Reviewer_Email"].ToString();
                    reviewer.EmailIDTeamLead = reader["EmailID_TeamLead"].ToString();
                    reviewer.TeamLeadName = reader["TeamLead_Name"].ToString();
                    reviewer.TeamLeadEmail = reader["TeamLead_Email"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Site = reader["Site"].ToString();
                    reviewer.BusinessUnit = reader["Business_Unit"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Group = reader["Group"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Station = reader["Station"].ToString();
                    reviewer.PKGDepartment = reader["Pkg_Department"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Region = reader["Region"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Account = reader["Account"].ToString();
                    reviewer.KeyField = reader["Key_Field"].ToString();
                    reviewer.EmailIDSiteManager = reader["EmailID_SiteManager"].ToString();
                    reviewer.SiteManagerName = reader["SiteManager_Name"].ToString();
                    reviewer.SiteManagerEmail = reader["SiteManager_Email"].ToString();
                    reviewer.EmailIDSiteDirector = reader["EmailID_SiteDirector"].ToString();
                    reviewer.SiteDirectorName = reader["SiteDirector_Name"].ToString();
                    reviewer.SiteDirectorEmail = reader["SiteDirector_Email"].ToString();
                    reviewer.EmailIDPresident = reader["EmailID_President"].ToString();
                    reviewer.PresidentName = reader["President_Name"].ToString();
                    reviewer.PresidentEmail = reader["President_Email"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Customer = reader["Customer"].ToString();
                    reviewer.Flag = reader["Flag"].ToString();
                    reviewer.CreatedBy = reader["CreatedBy"].ToString();
                    reviewer.DateCreated = reader["DateCreated"].ToString();
                    reviewer.LastUpdatedBy = reader["LastUpdatedBy"].ToString();
                    reviewer.DateUpdated = reader["DateUpdated"].ToString();
                    string[] row = { reviewer.EmailIDReviewer, reviewer.ReviewerName, reviewer.ReviewerEmail, reviewer.EmailIDTeamLead, reviewer.TeamLeadName,
                                     reviewer.TeamLeadEmail, reviewer.Site, reviewer.BusinessUnit, reviewer.Group,  reviewer.Station, reviewer.PKGDepartment,
                                     reviewer.Region, reviewer.Account, reviewer.KeyField, reviewer.EmailIDSiteManager, reviewer.SiteManagerName,
                                     reviewer.SiteManagerEmail, reviewer.EmailIDSiteDirector, reviewer.SiteDirectorName, reviewer.SiteDirectorEmail, reviewer.EmailIDPresident,
                                     reviewer.PresidentName, reviewer.PresidentEmail, reviewer.Customer, reviewer.Flag, reviewer.CreatedBy,
                                     reviewer.DateCreated, reviewer.LastUpdatedBy, reviewer.DateUpdated };
                    reviewers.Add(reviewer);
                }
                MaintReviewertbl.DataSource = reviewers;
                MaintReviewertbl.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you're using right syntax of `GROUP BY` clause? I'm sure you'll have syntax error if you add `TRUMPET`  to your query.

Comment: Just use bracket enclosure `[Group]` for `Group` column (which conflicts with `GROUP BY` keyword clause) & the query will run fine.

Comment: You can add a keyword as a field name by putting the name between [] in sql. ex.: "[group]"

Comment: "Group" is a reserved keyword. You can find complete answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52273/can-column-name-be-group-in-postgresql-or-in-any-databases)

Comment: side note: SqlDataReader also implements IDisposable. You might also want to check out [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper). It could make your code simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Its giving you an error because `Group` is a keyword(words that have a special meaning in SQL like `Select` and `from`). This `Group` is conflicting with `Group By` and you are using it as a column name. You should change your column name in the table to something like `Groupname` or `GroupType` anything that is not a keyword in SQL. This will solve the error.

Comment: Yes, Group is one of the column name in my table. But I can't change the name of the column in the table because the database that I'm using is not accessible by any users including me.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "select " +
                          "EmailID_Reviewer, " +
                          "[Group], " +
                          "from dbo.tblCSRMaintReviewer ";

Comment: I just did that a moment ago. But the message box produces the " [Group] "  message.

Comment: try this cmd.CommandText = "select " + "A.EmailID_Reviewer, " + "A.Group, " + "from dbo.tblCSRMaintReviewer A ";

Comment: Hate to say this but the second suggestion still produces the same output.

Comment: try to clean and build your solution again , sometimes the sdk does not take the changes and evaluates the cached queries which  keep on annoying us with the same output

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are having a column named `Group`, but it's a keyword So I suggest you to change the column name(if it will not need severe coding changes) or else simply enclose them in a pair of  `[]`, like this `[Group]`. Keep in mind its not a good practice to give such keywords for other purposes, they are already reserved for some other purposes

Comment: How can I do that without changing the column name in the table?

Comment: @HoneyBadger: use like this: `... "Business_Unit, " +
                          "[Group], " +
                          "Station, " +...`

Comment: I just did it. But it produces the same output.

Comment: What is happening now? are you getting the same error or something else